# How to covert java predicate to scala predicate

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have a java method which is accepting

```
predicate(Predicate<T> predicate)
```

my java class is

```
class Employee {

  String getEmployeeId() {
    return "";
  }

  boolean isManager() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

In java I can call

```
predicate(Employee::isManager)
```

how to do this in scala?

Comment: try `predicate(employee.isManager)`

Comment: Do you want to convert both class and `predicate` method to Scala? Or you want to use Java's method, i.e. `Employee::isManager` from Scala code?

Comment: The `T` parameter comes from the class definition?

Comment: @Duelist I want to access java method from scala code for that how to create a scala Employee class and method and how to call java predicate from scala

Answer (score 1):

This should work in scala

```
predicate[Employee](_.isManager)
```

Answer (score 1):

A Java Predicate is a Functional interface that, from the doc, "Represents a predicate (boolean-valued function) of one argument"

In the Scala language the concept of functional interface are supported by default, because Scala is a multi-paradigm language object oriented and functional programming.

So you need to think about the predicate interface like a lambda function that returns a boolean for certain input.

for example:

`predicate(p => p.isManager)`

But in the scala language, for this scenario you can use the special character _ so:

`predicate(_.isManager)`

Answer (score 1):

In scala we have lambdas, but the language doesn't have that more specific lambda like `Predicate`, that will be a function, that when called, will return a Boolean.

The type of Predicate in scala would be a `Function1[T, Boolean]` or with syntactic sugar `T => Boolean`.

Transforming your code to scala, the class that you have will be

```
class Employee {
  def getEmployeeId():String = {
    ""
    }

  def isManager(): Boolean = {
    true
    }
}
```

and the definition of the method predicate:

```
def predicate[T](f: T => Boolean): UnknownType = ???
```

To apply:

```
predicate[Employee](x => x.isManager)
// x will be of type Employee, as setted in the type parameter
//or with sugar
predicate[Employee](_.isManager) 
//you only use the obtained parameter once,
//so we can call it "wildcard" or `_`, and get it's method
```

[try it here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/sdKES7O/0).